# electric output signal (windows)

Tags: windows, signals

Is it possible to get an electric output signal from a Windows PC in order to control a Transistor?
If Usb or audio doesn't matter.
Also the Programming language doesn't matter.

If there is no way in windows is there a way in Unix systems like Linux?

Comment: you should post this question in arduino community they can help you ...

Comment: I did it now with an Arduino and its USB communication

Just if somebody searches here for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serial port sources a small amount of current at +12V/-12V. And the parallel port (if you have an old system) also sources current. Elsewhere I read it can source 2.6 milliamps. If your PC has neither kind of port you could always get a USB-to-serial device.

I found a lot of hits on google with "source current serial port pc" and "source current parallel port pc".